# Looking for impl of a Fuzzy Neural Network (FNN or SOFNN)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm looking for an implementation of FNN (or better yet, a SOFNN  as described by [Forecasting Time Series by SOFNN with Reinforcement Learning](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Forecasting-Time-Series-by-SOFNN-with-Reinforcement-Kuremoto-Obayashi/8a5ce65e52077303b8dcbe39a3953219e910ca3f)).  Any language, though preference is Java, C#, C++ in that order.

Comment: Hey @Jonathan; machine learning is on-topic here (in fact, the machine learning proposal was merged with this one): http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/492/are-the-machine-learning-questions-on-topic

Comment: Did you have any success in finding an implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not an expert on this subject, but I believe that FNN are sometimes referred to as a [neuro-fuzzy system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuro-fuzzy) (also [referenced here](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Fuzzy_neural_network)).

There are several implementations that I can find for that subject, including in [C++](http://fuzzy.cs.uni-magdeburg.de/nefcon/) and [Java](http://fuzzy.cs.uni-magdeburg.de/nefclass/nefclass-j/), but I can't confirm whether they would be relevant to your problem.

Comment: Thanks, you are right that FNN falls into the category of neuro-fuzzy systems.  The links you gave are helpful.  I think I will contact the author of the paper to see if there are closer implementations.